# How do I know the device path to an USB-stick?

Tags: usb, mount, devices

I have a USB-stick (used as an installation medium). Now I need to install a driver from a restricted folder on that device). But how do I get the device path to my USB-stick (e.g. `/dev/sda3` so I can mount it using the `mount` command?

I have read the answer to [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux-beginners-confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18927/1615) but `fdisk -l` shows nothing to me.

Comment: How about `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: This really doesn’t answer the question. If I needed a path for " /path/tousbstick" what path would I type in the command line?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/361885/how-do-i-figure-out-which-dev-is-a-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First plug in your USB-Stick.
Then type:

```
lsblk
```

Your output should look something like this

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  74,5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0 390,2G  0 part /home
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     1G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Now you can use the size to determine which one is your usb stick . To mount it somewhere in your home folder for example just type:

```
mkdir ~/UsbStick
sudo mount /dev/PATH_TO_YOUR_STICK ~/UsbStick
```

obviously replacing `PATH_TO_YOUR_STICK` with the right `/dev/sdX` path and `~/UsbStick` with the directory you created using the `mkdir` command

Answer (score 16):

find device path, LABEL, UUID and TYPE of block devices with help of command

```
sudo blkid
```

result will be like

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda6: UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="p" UUID="XXXX-XXXX" TYPE="vfat"
```

get your device path and fire mount command for usb-stick.

Answer (score 8):

### Device names of flash drives

A flash drive can be connected

- **via USB** (typically a USB stick or a memory card via a USB adapter)
- the device name is the same as for SATA drives, `/dev/sdx`
- and partitions are named `/dev/sdxn`

where **`x`** is the device letter and **`n`** the partition number, for example `/dev/sda1`

- **via PCI** (typically a memory card in a built-in slot in a laptop)
- the device name is `/dev/mmcblkm`
- and partitions are named `/dev/mmcblkmpn`

where **`m`** is the device number and **`n`** the partition number, for example `/dev/mmcblk0p1`

### Example with an SSD, HDD, USB pendrive and an SD card

**lsblk**

```
$ sudo lsblk -o model,name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint
MODEL            NAME        FSTYPE    SIZE LABEL              MOUNTPOINT
Samsung SSD 850  sda                 232,9G                    
                 ├─sda1      vfat      300M EFI                /boot/efi
                 ├─sda2                  1M                    
                 ├─sda3      ext4      100G root               
                 └─sda4      swap        5G                    [SWAP]
00BEKT-00PVMT0   sdb                 298,1G                    
                 ├─sdb1      vfat      480M                    
                 ├─sdb2      ext4       80G lubuntu-xenial64   /media/tester/lubuntu-xenial64
                 ├─sdb3      swap      3,9G                    [SWAP]
                 ├─sdb4      ext4      100G ubuntu-artful64x   /
                 └─sdb5      ext4    113,7G ubuntu-artful64w   /media/tester/ubuntu-artful64w
Extreme          sdc                  14,6G                    
                 ├─sdc1      ntfs      6,7G usbdata            /media/tester/usbdata1
                 ├─sdc2                  1M                    
                 ├─sdc3      vfat      244M usbboot            
                 ├─sdc4      iso9660   948M Lubuntu 17.10 i386 /media/tester/Lubuntu 17.10 i386
                 └─sdc5      ext4      6,7G casper-rw          /media/tester/casper-rw
                 mmcblk0               3,7G                    
                 ├─mmcblk0p1 ntfs      661M usbdata            /media/tester/usbdata
                 ├─mmcblk0p2             1K                    
                 ├─mmcblk0p3 vfat      122M usbboot            /media/tester/usbboot
                 ├─mmcblk0p4 iso9660   355M 9w-dus             /media/tester/9w-dus
                 └─mmcblk0p5 ext4      2,6G persistence        /media/tester/persistence
```

Edit for `lsblk` list: With modern versions of Ubuntu you need not use `sudo`, and when there are (many) snaps, and we don't want them to clutter the list, you the following command line,

```
lsblk -o model,name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint | grep -v " loop.*snap"
```

**parted**

```
$ sudo parted -ls
[sudo] password for tester: 
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  316MB  315MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      316MB   317MB  1049kB
 3      317MB   108GB  107GB   ext4            root
 4      244GB   249GB  5369MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: WDC WD32 00BEKT-00PVMT0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      33,6MB  537MB   503MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      537MB   86,4GB  85,9GB  ext4
 4      86,4GB  194GB   107GB   ext4
 5      194GB   316GB   122GB   ext4
 3      316GB   320GB   4161MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: SanDisk Extreme (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 15,7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 2      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               primary  bios_grub
 3      2097kB  258MB   256MB   fat32        primary  boot, esp
 4      258MB   1252MB  994MB                primary
 5      1252MB  8473MB  7221MB  ext2         primary
 1      8473MB  15,7GB  7221MB  ntfs         primary  msftdata


Model: SD SD04G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3965MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 3      2097kB  130MB   128MB   primary   fat32        boot
 4      130MB   502MB   372MB   primary
 2      502MB   3272MB  2769MB  extended               lba
 5      503MB   3272MB  2768MB  logical   ext2
 1      3272MB  3965MB  693MB   primary   ntfs
```

Comment: I have to grep out the snap loops extending your command as: sudo lsblk -o model,name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint | grep -v " loop.*snap"

Comment: @thanos.a, You are right. I can improve this answer by removing the loop devices from the list. Tthanks for the heads up :-)

Comment: +1 this is the best answer. Both show me were my USB stick is. Without need to guess it by using its size.

Answer (score 3):

Check how many USB ports available in your machine so that we can connect USB devices to these ports.

```
find /dev/bus/
```

[Source](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/05/find-usb-device-details-in-linuxunix-using-lsusb-command.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me -

I have connected my Android device via USB.

To find mount point -

1) Go to Files - 
[files application using GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YGaa.png)(attached image)

2) Right click on Disk whether it is USB or Phone Disk -

3) Click on Open in Terminal.

In my case, it was mounted under /run/user, and when doing lsblk no disk was added, because it was adding in the tmpfs filesystem

You can also check using ***df -h*** where tmpfs filesystem is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get the path of the mounted USB is open *Files*, right-click on the USB in the sidebar and click *properties*. Concatentate the *parent folder* entry with the name of the USB (look at topbar for name). for example: `/home/user/1234-ABCD`.